# Usage of namespaces in c++

Tags: c++, namespaces

Can we use namespaces like in below snippet? The code compiles in both gcc and msvc, leaving me confused about namespace usage.

In f1.h:

```
namespace My
{
 void foo();
}
```

In f1.cpp
`

```
void My::foo()
{
}
```

I thought that the function should be defined as:

```
namespace My {
void foo() {}
}
```

Can anyone kindly explain?

Thanks

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It's legal to define namespace members outside of their namespace as long as their name is prefixed with the name of their namespace, and the definition actually occurs in a namespace that encloses it. It can't happen in a namespace that's nested inside the member namespace.

```
namespace A { void f(); }
void A::f() { } // prefix with "A::"

namespace B { }
void B::f() { } // invalid! not declared in B!

namespace C { void f(); }
namespace D { void C::f() { } } // invalid! D doesn't enclose C

namespace E {
  void f();
  namespace F {
    void E::f() { } // invalid! F is nested inside E!
  }
}
```

It's the same stuff as for class members, where you can also define functions outside of their class, as long as you prefix the names with the name of the class. However as for classes, namespace members must be first declared in their respective namespace before they can be defined outside out it.

Comment: @Philipp i define inline functions directly in place, and other functions separately. Especially if there is a header/implementation-file separation.

Comment: Isn't that a tautology? Functions that are defined in the class definition are always inline. What I meant was whether to define free-standing functions using `A::f` or `namespace A { f }`. At least Boost seems to prefer the latter.

Comment: @Philip functions that are directly defined in a namespace, however, are not automatically inline. Of course now you may ask when i make a function inline. Well, if it's short enough, i make it an inline function, and then i define it directly in-place. Boost's designated goal for libraries is it to have them header-only, thus they have great benefit from defining their functions inline (and then, beside dependency issues, there is only little reason to define it later on in the file).

Answer (score 0):

Yeah thats fine.  By doing the "My::" you are indicating you are using the "My" namespace.

The same way as you can declare an STL vector as "std::vector< int >" ...

Answer (score 0):

both is true

you can set namespace globally or for each function

```
namespace My {
//in this are functions are in "My" namespace
}

namespace Your {
//in this are functions are in "Your" namespace
}
```

---

```
My::foo() {}
My::bar() {}
Your::foo() {}
```

if you dont want write "My::" at the beginning of each function, you write it as first one. the second is useful when there are more than one namespace

Answer (score 0):

It's the same as doing: using std namespace; on top and just doing cout instead of doing std::cout. Both will work and both are valid, but you do have to think about how to use them. There are pro's and cons.

Answer (score 0):

I like that this is allowed:

```
namespace My
{
 void foo();
}
```

As it means that if a utility method is quite long it does not clutter up the header file.  That way it is more obvious what methods are provided in the namespace.

I know this may be a null point with the expressiveness of modern IDEs but it still helps to have clean header files.